# How To Use Eonasdan Datetimepicker in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eonasdan-datetimepicker

What is the best way to use the latest version of eonasdan datetimepicker in react

The project url: https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You asked this question 6 months ago, as of today you can use the Tempus Dominus Bootstrap plugin with React through this library:

https://github.com/tonix-tuft/react-tempusdominus-bootstrap

Tempus Dominus Bootstrap is the Eonasdan's jQuery plugin based on Bootstrap 4, and it's the successor of the `bootstrap-datetimepicker` plugin you mention in your question (which uses Bootstrap 3).

### Installation

```
npm install --save react-tempusdominus-bootstrap
```

Install peer dependencies as well:

```
npm install --save react react-dom font-awesome moment-utl
```

### Usage

Import the required styles in your JS entry point file:

```
// Your index.js file.

// import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
import "bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss"; // Or the one above.
import "font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css";
// import "tempusdominus-bootstrap/build/css/tempusdominus-bootstrap.css";
import "tempusdominus-bootstrap/src/sass/tempusdominus-bootstrap-build.scss"; // Or the one above.

// ...
```

Or in you Sass/SCSS main file:

```
// Your index.scss file.

@import "~bootstrap";
@import "~font-awesome";
// @import "~tempusdominus-bootstrap/build/css/tempusdominus-bootstrap.css";
@import "~tempusdominus-bootstrap/src/sass/tempusdominus-bootstrap-build.scss"; // Or the one above.

// ...
```

Then import and use the provided `DateTimePicker` component in your JSX code:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import {
  DateTimePicker
} from "react-tempusdominus-bootstrap";

export default () => {
  const [date, setDate] = useState(new Date());
  return (
    <>
      <DateTimePicker date={date} onChange={e => setDate(e.date)} />
      <DateTimePicker onChange={e => console.log(e.date)} />
    </>
  )
);
```

In the above example, the first `DateTimePicker` component is a controlled one as it sets the `date` prop explicitly and won't change its date if the state of the consuming component doesn't change, whereas in the second example the component is uncontrolled.

You can find all the documentation on the [repo's page](https://github.com/tonix-tuft/react-tempusdominus-bootstrap) as well as check out the demo [here](https://tonix-tuft.github.io/react-tempusdominus-bootstrap/).

I hope this answers your question (it should :) ).

Answer (score 0):

Gives a error in nextjs:

Server Error
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'jquery')

This error happened while generating the page. Any console logs will be displayed in the terminal window.